# Using POS Taggers will raise wrong format in German

Tags: stanford-nlp

I encountered some question about annotation German corpus, while it's normal for English corpus.
For example:

**Original Sentence :**
( Foto unten ) RI Director Kjell-Åke Åkesson ( Schweden ) , Mitglied des NID-Tea    ms , bei der Impfung eines Kindes in Indien .

**Annotation Sentence :**

1. (_XY Foto_NN unten_ADV )_CARD RI_NE Director_NE Kjell-胈NE
2. ke_XY 胈XY
3. kesson_NE (_VVFIN Schweden_NE )*NE ,*$, Mitglied_NN des_ART
   NID-Teams_NN ,_$, be    i_APPR der_ART Impfung_NN eines_ART
   Kindes_NN in_APPR Indien_NE ._$.

In this case,the char "Å" will give rise to a change and cause a newline, therefore,the whole corpus would increase by 4000 lines.

By the way, my program command is as follow:

```
java -mx8g -classpath stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -tokenize false -sentenceDelimiter newline -model models/german-hgc.tagger -textFile /data/mmyin/wmt17_de_en/test_1 > /data/mmyin/wmt17_de_en/test_pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I would suggest using the full pipeline.

You can download it here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Here is a sample command for running on German text:

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

Answer (score 0):

@StanfordNLPHelp

Thanks for your reply! This is helpful for me.But , there are some questions for me.
Firstly，the toolkit is uesed to process about 5 million lines German corpus ，but the corpus sentence contain some ending punctuation in the middle or some sentences lack ending punctuation . Therefore, it could arise some mistakes.For example:

**Original Sentence:**

unter dem diesjährigen Motto " Ideen bringen Europa voran ! " knüpft die Kampagne an das Jahr der Kreativität und Innovation an .

**Annotated Sentence:**

*Sentence #1 (11 tokens):*
unter dem diesjährigen Motto " Ideen bringen Europa voran ! "

*Sentence #2 (12 tokens):*
knüpft die Kampagne an das Jahr der Kreativität und Innovation an .

In this case, I do not want one sentence splited to two sentences.

Lastly, the output format looks like this

[Text=unter CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=5 PartOfSpeech=APPR].

I only want to get PartOfSpeech for per word in a sentence, then output to a line.

What can I do?

Comment: You can change "-outputFormat conll" or "-outputFormat conllu".  The sentence splitting issue is unfortunately a deficiency in our rule based sentence splitting.  If you have another sentence splitting tool you want to use you could use that and create a file with one sentence per line.  Then you can use the option "-ssplit.eolonly"